# Archive a directory to stdout with encrypting file names from Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, encryption, 7-zip, archiving

I have a 1 TB directory that needs to be uploaded as a single encrypted file. There is no free space on a disk. I already have an app to upload a file from stdin but I don't know how to create the archive stream.

No compression is needed at all.

It's important that file names inside the archive must be encrypted. If an archive format doesn't support this then it can be emulated by creating a nested archive but it needs to be streamed too.

I'm experimenting using 7zip:

`myuploader.exe < 7z a null -so -tgzip -siInner.gzip < 7z a null -so -tgzip -siFile.mp4 < d:\source_file.mp4`

But in Windows it's even not possible to pipe one command into another like this.

Also `-p` switch has no effect with `-so`.

How can I do the task?

Comment: You say the file must be encrypted, then you say that no encryption is needed at all, then you say that file names must be encrypted?

Comment: @user1686 sorry, I wanted to write only "no compression". Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: I think in windows you will need enough room to create your archive before uploading it.  And you say `pipe` as in `|` when I think you mean `redirect` as in `>` or `<`.  Not the same thing.  Windows cmd can do this but I think not as well as Linux.  Powershell can but I still don't have an answer for you.. perhaps someone else will come along that can.

Comment: how about to  install cygwin ?